# Write a function from csv using dataframes to read and return column values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data set in a csv file:

```
vehicle---time-----aspd[m/s]------gspd[m/s]----hdg---alt[m-msl]

veh_1---17:19.5---0.163471505---0.140000001---213---273.8900146
veh_2---17:19.5---0.505786836---0.170000002---214---273.9100037
veh_3---17:19.8---0.173484877---0.109999999---213---273.980011
veh_4---44:12.4---18.64673424---19.22999954---316---388.9299927
veh_5---44:13.0---18.13533401---19.10000038---316---389.1700134
```

I am trying to write a function launch_time() with two inputs (dataframe, vehicle name) that returns the first time the gspd is reported above 10.0 m/s.
The output time must be converted from a string (HH:MM:SS.SS) to a minutes after 12:00 format.

It should look something like this:

```
>>> launch_time(df, veh_1)
30.0
```

I will use this function to iterate through each vehicle and then need to record the results into a list of tuples with the format (v_name, launch time) in launch sequence order.

It should look something like this:

```
'veh_1', 30.0, 'veh_2', 15.0
```

Disclosure: my python/pandas knowledge is very entry-level.

Comment: pandas `read_csv` accepts a custom delimiter, such as `'---'`. Have you tried that?

Comment: There are no '---' in the file.  I was using that initially to make the columns more clear, but it just added confusion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with separator `-{3,}` - read csv with 3 and more `-`:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""vehicle---time-----aspd[m/s]------gspd[m/s]----hdg---alt[m-msl]

veh_1---17:19.5---0.163471505---0.140000001---213---273.8900146
veh_2---17:19.5---0.505786836---0.170000002---214---273.9100037
veh_3---17:19.8---0.173484877---0.109999999---213---273.980011
veh_4---44:12.4---18.64673424---19.22999954---316---388.9299927
veh_5---45:13.0---18.13533401---19.10000038---316---389.1700134"""
#after testing replace StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep="-{3,}", engine='python')

print (df)
  vehicle     time  aspd[m/s]  gspd[m/s]  hdg  alt[m-msl]
0   veh_1  17:19.5   0.163472       0.14  213  273.890015
1   veh_2  17:19.5   0.505787       0.17  214  273.910004
2   veh_3  17:19.8   0.173485       0.11  213  273.980011
3   veh_4  44:12.4  18.646734      19.23  316  388.929993
4   veh_5  45:13.0  18.135334      19.10  316  389.170013
```

Then convert column `time` [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html), filter all rows above `10m/s` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), group on vehicles using [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html), then get the [first value in each group](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#taking-the-first-rows-of-each-group) and last `zip` columns `vehicle` and `time` and convert to `list`:

```
df.time = pd.to_timedelta('00:' + df.time, unit='h').\
              astype('timedelta64[m]').astype(int)
req = df[df['gspd[m/s]'] > 10].\
          sort_values('time', ascending=True).\
          groupby('vehicle', as_index=False).head(1)
print(req)
  vehicle  time  aspd[m/s]  gspd[m/s]  hdg  alt[m-msl]
4   veh_5    45  18.135334      19.10  316  389.170013
3   veh_4    44  18.646734      19.23  316  388.929993

L = list(zip(req['vehicle'],req['time']))
print (L)
[('veh_5', 45), ('veh_4', 44)]
```

Comment: For each vehicle is only one row or there can be multiple rows? In column `time` are sometimes `hour`? Format in sample is  `MM:SS.SS` ? Time in `minutes` can be rounded?

Comment: you are missing the OP's question. OP needs the time from the first row where `gspd` > 10m/s. After you get the time converted correctly to `int`, you need to group on `vehicle`, sort on `time`, and return the first. Basically: `req =  df[df['gspd[m/s]'] > 10].groupby('vehicle).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('time', ascending=True).head(1))`...

Comment: Thank you, I add it to answer.

Comment: Ok, no problem, ;) I have a bit improving your comment, something like `df = df[df['gspd[m/s]'] > 10].sort_values('time', ascending=True).groupby('vehicle', as_index=False).first()
`

Comment: Done, I used your improvement! Just used `head(1)` instead of `first` because that's what the linked docs say.

Comment: There are no '----' in original file. There are hundreds of rows for each of 5 vehicles. The hour is 12 for all times; should be 12:MM:SS.S.  Yes, time in minutes can be rounded.  Originally had the following code for time conversion:                                                                                        def time_convert(str_time):
    values = str_time.split(':')
    mins = 60*(float(values[0]) - 12) + float(values[1]) + 1.0/60 * float(values[2])
    mins = round(mins,4)
    return mins

Comment: @CatLady - no problem, use normal separator.

Comment: @CatLady - I try use your function, but I get error. But I think you can use `df.time = df.time.apply(time_convert)` instead `df.time = pd.to_timedelta('00:' + df.time, unit='h').astype('timedelta64[m]').astype(int)`

Comment: @CatLady, you may use `pd.to_timedelta('12:' + df.time, unit='h')` instead. I would prefer this.

Comment: @jezrael, Using your suggestion of df.time = df.time.apply with my nested function worked! Thanks!

Comment: @jezrael    Addendum question:  Trying to calculate the average of the four launch time intervals (veh_1 to veh_2; veh_2 to veh_3, veh_4 to veh_5).  Would I just use a variation of df['time'].mean()  ??

Comment: @Kartik Addendum question: Trying to calculate the average of the four launch time intervals (veh_1 to veh_2; veh_2 to veh_3, veh_4 to veh_5). Would I just use a variation of df['time'].mean() ??

Comment: @CatLady, I recommend you post a new question to seek answers for that, as it does not belong in this answer. This is an answer about grouping, and aggregating. Also, your comment is not clear enough, mainly because we do not know all that you know about your project. We cannot follow up on questions like that.